# How to use where clause inside Laravel sql database relations

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to search on last Apologies using national where equals national_id that comes from students function, how can I do that?

I tried:

```
return [
    'Students' => function ($students){
        $students->select('id', 'username','national_id', 'is_foreigner', 'college_id')
            ->with([
                'Apologies' => function ($apologies) use ($students) {

                    $apologies->select('student_id', 'reasons');
                    ->where('national', 'students.national_id');
                }
            ]);
    }
]
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after the select.

Comment: I already removed it but the same problem @aynber